# Is GeoLite2 is supported on the web rest service

Tags: geoip, maxmind

I need to use GeoLite2, but I don't need whole of data, is a way to get some connections info from rest service?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to use remote REST API and no database?

If yes, you can use the free IPInfoDB web service at https://ipinfodb.com/api

It has been is service since 2010.

Comment: I need a REST for getter information about a client from which country and maybe the city is connected. I don't need the whole list of information, I need only info of MY connected clients, not whole world DB so: First-time I'll send a query for users that not stored on my DB, after that when client reconnect/connect again information will be stored in DB so I don't need to send a query again. Question is how often they update the DB?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the IP Geolocation API web service at https://geo.ipify.org